# for-loop javascript beginner

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am learning JavaScript `for loop` where I tried running this code in google chrome developers tools where the output made me more confused. Can someone explain me what this code is doing.

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

I was expecting the result as `6`, as the "test condition" given is `i <= 6` but I got the output as `20`. How I am getting `20` here when the loop has to stop at `6`

Comment: It sums up all the values of `i`, and 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 is 20

Comment: If you want `sum` to read `6`, you should increment by 1 at every iteration, i.e. `sum++` instead of `sum + i`.

Comment: @Terry: That should provide `5` since it starts at `2`.

Comment: If OP changes `let i = 1; i <= 6` or `let i = 0; i < 6` in conjunction with using `sum++` then that will work

Comment: Yes it would.. naturally if one changes everything the output gets different.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't adds `1` in each iteration it adds the value of `i` which increase in each loop.

```
sum = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6
```

You can see what's happening in your code in the below snippet

```js
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 2; i <=6; i++){
  sum = sum + i;
  console.log(`sum = ${sum - i} + ${i} = ${sum}`)
}
console.log(sum)
```

If you will increment sum by `1` and start loop at `1` instead of `2` then the result value will be `6`

```js
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 1; i <=6; i++){
  sum = sum + 1;
}
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation, I was looking for this... now I understood how Javascript works in for loop.

Comment: @Zeba Consider accepting the answer if you thinks it best for you.

Answer (score 1):

in 1st line, you have assigned sum as initially zero.
for loop, 
the loop will start with taking initial of i i.e 2 and stop when it is 6 i.e i<=6

i = 2 .... sum = sum + i; ... sum = 0 + 2 = 2

i = 3 .... sum = sum + i; ... sum = 2 + 3 = 5

i = 4 .... sum = sum + i; ... sum = 5 + 4 = 9

i = 5 .... sum = sum + i; ... sum = 9 + 5 = 14

i = 6 .... sum = sum + i; ... sum = 14 + 6 = 20

so your final output is 20